# How can I test for stdout using behave?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bdd, python-behave

I would like to create a Hello World command line application with BDD using ***python3*** and ***behave***. I have my features file set up this way:

```
Feature: Hello World

  Scenario: the program greets us
    When I start the program
    Then it prints "Hello World!"
```

In my `features/steps/hello.py` the outline of my `@Then` step is this:

```
from behave import *

@then('it prints "{text}"')
def step_impl(context, text):
    # what goes here???
```

How can I test the output of my program? How can I capture stdout for this test?

Comment: I see your first step is "I start the program". Are you launching a child process there? And then you have to check *that process'* output?

Comment: @Louis I could launch a child process but I was lazy and simply invoked the main() function.

Answer (score 0):

One of the typical ways to check the `print` output is to hijack `sys.stdout` and analyze it:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys

real_stdout = sys.stdout
try:
  mock_stdout = StringIO()
  sys.stdout = mock_stdout
  print "Hi there"
  assert mock_stdout.getvalue() == "Hi there"
finally:
  sys.stdout = real_stdout
```

Of course, the try/finally logic may be implicit in the testing framework you use. In `unittest`, it would be `setUp` / `tearDown`; I have no idea about `behave` but its docs likely cover it.

Comment: This is https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout, by the way.

Comment: @JoshLee: Could you make an answer out of your comment? (I had to use stdout redirection maybe once in my life, wasn't aware, thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Here's 9000's idea applied to behave:

I redirect stdout to a mock in the file named `features/environment.py`:

```
import sys
import io

def before_all(context):
    context.real_stdout = sys.stdout
    context.stdout_mock = io.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = context.stdout_mock

def after_all(context):
    sys.stdout = context.real_stdout
```

And then in `features/steps/hello.py` I assert on the contents of the mock stdout:

```
@then('it prints "{text}"')
    def step_impl(context, text):
    output = context.stdout_mock.getvalue()
    assertEqual( "Hello World!\n", output )
```